# Como atualizar docker-compose

Tags: php, servidor, docker

Alguem sabe como atualizar docker-compose para a versão mais recente? 
A minha se encontra na 1.5.x e me deparo com alguns problemas como

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have
>   any configuration options. All top level keys in your
>   docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options

Comment: Pedro, tente este tutorial se teu server for Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934675/ubuntu-and-updating-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A atualização do Docker compose vai depender do sistema que você está utilizando.

No Windows e no MacOS eles são atualizados junto com o instalador do Docker nesses plataformas, o que não ocorre quando atualizamos o Docker a partir de um repositório (`apt-get upgrade`).

Para a atualização no Linux, o repositório do [Docker Compose no github](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) tem a versão mais atualizada. O próprio release te fala o que você precisa rodar para isso:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Isso irá instalar a versão 1.9.0 do Docker Compose (repare na url) e mover o executável para outro local já disponível no seu `PATH`. Talvez seja preciso permissões de super usuário para isso.